# Overflow Menu on iPad SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have an issue with Overflow Menu. When the iPad goes in SplitView I see the menu but when I click on it, it does not function. What I want to do is that when it goes in SplitView, I should be able to stack my 5 icons in a menu. Thank you!

[image: I have 5 trailing Icons]

[image: This is the issue]

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Image("terrain")
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .secondaryAction) {
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                    }
                    
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .topBarTrailing) {
                    ControlGroup {
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                        
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                        
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                        
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                        
                        Button {
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                        
                    } label: {
                        Label ("More", systemImage: "ellipse.circle")
                    }
                    }
                }.toolbarRole(.editor)//Toolbar
            }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
        }
```